# MySQL query to normalise datetime field

Tags: mysql

I have an application that used to insert a datetime field. There was an issue though that it would insert with the seconds and it wasn't supposed to!

I.e. 2011-08-07 15:24:06

They have corrected this and inserts now only include up to the minute so the above example would look like

2011-08-07 15:24:00

There are 20 million rows "wrong" at the moment. What is the most efficient query to fix the old ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE
  table
SET
  timefield = DATE_FORMAT(timefield,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00')
WHERE
  SECOND(timefield) <> 0;
```

This will have to read each row of the table and extract the `seconds` part of the time (this is unavoidable), but it won't have to update rows which already are correct.

Comment: But won't I need to use :00 instead of :%s ??

Answer (score -1):

Probably filter your update based on the 'wrong' ones then do a right trim of the last 3 characters.

Comment: But a trim will remove those characters? I can easily filter as I know when it changed but have you got an example of the update statement?

Comment: Emil's answer will wrk better for you.